# Kind of values(convention) of input parameters in setRPY from tf::Quaternion class

Tags: quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know about setRPY method in defined in tf::Quaternion class. I couldn't find the API documentation describing it. What range of values in the input parameters(values of roll, pitch and yaw) does it expect? Is it:

1. -180 to 180 or
2. 0 to 360

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12989/kind-of-values(convention)-of-input-parameters-in-setrpy-from-tf::quaternion-class/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-02-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[ROS standard units of measure](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html)

Angles are represented in radians. It does not make a difference whether you represent them in the `0` to `2pi` range, or the `-pi` to `pi` range

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It expects angles in radians, as with all angular units in ROS. See http://ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html and http://www.ros.org/doc/unstable/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Quaternion.html#ab34dfef6a01c1ece07bea92d485b0576

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-02-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2